# Audio File Speech Recognition in Python - location of word in seconds

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I've been experimenting with the python speech recognition library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

To read downloaded versions of the BBC shipping forecast. The clipping of those files from live radio to the iplayer are obviously automated and not very accurate - so usually there is some audio before the forecast itself starts - a trailer, or the end of the news. I don't need to be that accurate but I'd like to get speech recognition to recognise the phrase "and now the shipping forecast" (or just 'shipping' would do actually) and cut the file from there.

My code so far (adpated form an example) transcribes and audio file of the forecast and uses a formula (based on 200 words per minute) to predict where the word shipping comes, but it's not proving to be very accurate.

Is there a way of getting the actual 'frame' or second onset that pocketsphinx itself detected for that word? I can't find anything in the documentation. Anyone any ideas?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "test_short2.wav")

# use the audio file as the audio source
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

# recognize speech using Sphinx
try:
    print "Sphinx thinks you said "
    returnedSpeech = str(r.recognize_sphinx(audio))

    wordsList = returnedSpeech.split()
    print returnedSpeech
    print "predicted loacation of start ", float(wordsList.index("shipping")) * 0.3


except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

Comment: Use binary search or similar, generating a new wave file that is for example half of the original, or similar, then find out which part contains the word `shipping`... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use pocketsphinx API directly for such things. It is also highly recommended to read pocketsphinx [documentation on keyword spotting](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutoriallm/#keyword-lists).

You can spot for keyphrase as demonstrated in [example](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/swig/python/test/kws_test.py):

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/en-us'))
config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'shipping forecast')
config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e-30)

stream = open(os.path.join(datadir, "test_short2.wav"), "rb")

decoder = Decoder(config)
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
         decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
    else:
         break
    if decoder.hyp() != None:
        print ([(seg.word, seg.prob, seg.start_frame, seg.end_frame) for seg in decoder.seg()])
        print ("Detected keyphrase, restarting search")
        decoder.end_utt()
        decoder.start_utt()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an error 

      "decoder = Decoder(config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\pocketsphinx.py", line 277, in __init__
    this = _pocketsphinx.new_Decoder(*args)
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1"

Is there another package I need to import?

Comment: You need to specify the model path properly

Comment: Thanks again Nikolay  

I have                 

`modeldir = "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/pocketsphinx/model"`  
 
`config = Decoder.default_config()`<br/>
`config.set_string('-hmm', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/en-us'))`  
`config.set_string('-dict', os.path.join(modeldir, 'en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict'))`  
`config.set_string('-keyphrase', 'shipping forecast')`  
`config.set_float('-kws_threshold', 1e-30)`  

and still no luck

Comment: Ok and what is the actual model location?

Comment: Although looking in my python folders there's only 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model\en-us' - one en-us, but even changing to this path for the model doesn't work

Comment: Something to do with windows paths?

Comment: `config.set_string('-hmm', 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\model\en-us')` then. You also need to properly point to a path to the dictionary file.

Comment: Although the script doesn't seem to output anything. Another parameter to tweak?

Comment: Time to read the documentation linked above and play with the threshold.